# Can't change owner or group of copied files. Strange permissions listing

Tags: linux, file-permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I copied a bunch of files from a Mac onto a USB SSD drive. Now I'm trying to look at them in Windows, or in Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu. I'm getting permission errors for everything.

What is the deal with the `----------` in the file listing?

Rescuable?

Suggestions?

```
balter@spectre:/mnt/D/Save/Pictures$ ls -al
total 2256
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     512 Jun 30  2017 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     512 Jun 30  2017 ..
---------- 1 root root    6148 Jun 29  2017 .DS_Store
---------- 1 root root       0 Dec 28  2016 .localized
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     512 Jun 30  2017 Photos Library.photoslibrary
---------- 1 root root  397686 May 10  2017 Picture1.png
---------- 1 root root   96403 May  4  2017 styx_you_are_here.jpg
---------- 1 root root 1795658 May  4  2017 styx_you_are_here.png
balter@spectre:/mnt/D/Save/Pictures$ sudo chmod 777 *
chmod: changing permissions of 'Picture1.png': Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of 'styx_you_are_here.jpg': Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of 'styx_you_are_here.png': Permission denied
balter@spectre:/mnt/D/Save/Pictures$ sudo chown balter *
balter@spectre:/mnt/D/Save/Pictures$ ls -al
total 2256
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     512 Jun 30  2017 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     512 Jun 30  2017 ..
---------- 1 root root    6148 Jun 29  2017 .DS_Store
---------- 1 root root       0 Dec 28  2016 .localized
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     512 Jun 30  2017 Photos Library.photoslibrary
---------- 1 root root  397686 May 10  2017 Picture1.png
---------- 1 root root   96403 May  4  2017 styx_you_are_here.jpg
---------- 1 root root 1795658 May  4  2017 styx_you_are_here.png
balter@spectre:/mnt/D/Save/Pictures$ sudo chgrp balter *
balter@spectre:/mnt/D/Save/Pictures$ ls -al
total 2256
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     512 Jun 30  2017 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     512 Jun 30  2017 ..
---------- 1 root root    6148 Jun 29  2017 .DS_Store
---------- 1 root root       0 Dec 28  2016 .localized
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     512 Jun 30  2017 Photos Library.photoslibrary
---------- 1 root root  397686 May 10  2017 Picture1.png
---------- 1 root root   96403 May  4  2017 styx_you_are_here.jpg
---------- 1 root root 1795658 May  4  2017 styx_you_are_here.png
```

### Edit:

Filesystem information:

```
balter@spectre:/mnt$ df -Th D
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
D:             drvfs   56G   35G   22G  62% /mnt/D
```

Comment: What filesystem is on that usb drive? If it is readable by Windows chances are that the original permissions are already gone.

Comment: Also note that the Windows Subsystem for Linux just adds another layer on the filesystem ... I haven't tried it, but I doubt that you can do much with permissions directly on actual drives.

Comment: Filesystem is `drvfs`. See edit to post.

Comment: FWIW, WSL is awesome!

Comment: It is, but it's not a real Linux. If you really need to set correct permissions and ownership I'd format that USB drive with a Linux native filesystem, copy the files again and then do whatever you are trying to do on a machine directly running Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking directly at the filesystem.

Keep in mind that WSL is running on top of Windows. Windows mounts the drive (I assume it is formatted with FAT32, which doesn't really know permissions) and shows a virtual representation of what is on that drive. If you look around on your regular hard drive within WSL you'll see that the permissions look similar everywhere.

You can't change permissions or ownerships of files outside your virtual root filesystem within WSL.

If you really need to set correct permissions and ownership I'd format that USB drive with a Linux native filesystem, copy the files again and then do whatever you are trying to do on a machine directly running Linux (or Mac, if you have another one available).